# No message found under code 'email.subject' for locale 'en_US'

Tags: java, spring, localization

I have property resource files for different localization. I set my default locale like this `Locale.forLanguageTag("en")`.

I retreive the property like this: `messageSource.getMessage("email.subject", null, Locale.getDefault().stripExtensions());`

However, my application fails with error `No message found under code 'email.subject' for locale 'en_US'.` My property file has suffix `_en`, so I understand that it can't find it - but my question is: why does it search for locale `en_US` instead of `en`?

For other languages (that doesn't have this region suffix), it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I set my default locale like this Locale.forLanguageTag("en").

The method `forLanguageTag` does *not* set a default locale. `Locale.setDefault(Locale)` does (only for the current instance of the JVM).

My guess is that your default locale is `en_US` and while it may *seem* as if your code adds a region for some reason, it actually did not set a new default locale and kept your original `en_US`.

I have set up a small test to illustrate it:

```java
public class MessageSourceTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException expEx = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void test() {

        expEx.expectMessage("No message found under code 'email.subject' for locale 'en_CA'");

        Locale.setDefault(Locale.CANADA);

        Locale.forLanguageTag("en");

        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:nonexistingResourceBundleButDoesntMatter");
        messageSource.getMessage("email.subject", null, Locale.getDefault().stripExtensions());
    }
}
```

The exception refers to the locale set by `Locale.setDefault(Locale.CANADA)` instead of the method invocation `Locale.forLanguageTag("en");`.

Comment: I didn't call that `Locale.forLanguageTag()` alone - it was an argument in method setLocale(). But that method was called on some unrelated bean (as I later found out) - I didn't set anything globally. So your answer did the trick for me :) Thanks!